# Duplicate namespace declarations in JAXB generated XML

Tags: java, jaxb

I am using JAXB to generate XML from Java objects, it's a realtime, quite high message rate application and works fine most of the time.  However occassionally and without any obvious clues as to why, I am getting duplicate namespace declarations in the generated XML.  eg:

```
<UpdateRequest xmlns="http://xml.mycomp.com/ns/myservice" 
               xmlns="http://xml.mycomp.com/ns/myservice">
    <field1>value</field1>
    ...
</UpdateRequest>
```

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Comment: Odd... can you post the JAXB-annotated java classes that generate this XML?

Comment: I'd like too but I don't think the firm would like it.  What's odd is that 99.9% of the time the object is being marshalled OK, then very occasionally we'll get this problem.  We're assuming multi-threading issues right now..

Answer (score 0):

Check if the xsd code of this class allow the creation of more than 1 instance of the repeated attribute. if so, you can avoid this repetitions setting the number of instances of the **xmlns** attribute for each **UpdateRequest** object.

If the problem is your code (maybe there is being created this attribute twice) and you have limited the number of instances of the attribute (as i said above), the program will show an error at runtime complaining that you are trying to insert an attribute already defined.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a repeated attribute, it's a repeated xmlns="blah" in the top level element of the XML

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be available at this [link](http://old.nabble.com/Duplicated-namespace-declaration-from-output-xml-td20069914.html).

here's the relevant section  quoted verbatim from the above link that may be relevant for you:

> Similar explicit inclusion of a schema
>   type in an instance document's element
>   occurs if you instantiate a JAXB
>   element using an object of some
>   (abstract) XML schema base type so
>   that the element would have the
>   element tag of the base type.
>
> Second, avoid xs:anySimpleType since
>   this will also create multiple
>   references to the namespaces bound to
>   xsi and xs, and type attributes
>   containing the actual type. And you
>   lose JAXB's advantage of having typed
>   fields in your Java classes so that
>   you lose all the checks the Java
>   compiler might do, and for
>   unmarshalling you'll have to handle
>   all the conversions yourself.