# JAXB lists namespaces in root element (-> each element)

Tags: xml, serialization, jaxb, marshalling, jaxb2

By default, jaxb 2 lists all (all possible required) namespaces in root element during marshalling:

Is there a way to describe namespace in each element instead of root element ?:

It also solves the problem of "unnecessary namespaces", which is also important in my case.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673626/jaxb-appending-unneeded-namespace-declarations-to-tags and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131376/duplicate-namespace-declarations-in-jaxb-generated-xml

Comment: You shouldn't care, as long as the namespaces are semantically correct.

Comment: sometimes, it matters and it is good to have an opportunity to define strategy of namespace description (in root or in each element) using property of marshaller.

Comment: Yes, but it *shouldn't* matter. If it does matter, the system has been poorly designed.

Comment: i'm not an xml expert, but as far as i know there is no such restriction (namespaces to be described in root) in xml spec, so the library should not impose such restrictions but give freedom to developer

Comment: You're missing my point. Your application should not care how the XML namespaces are specified in the XML document, as long as they are semantically correct. If your application requires the namespaces to be done in a certain way, your application needs redesigning. This is not a restriction of JAXB, it's part of the XML namespace design philosophy. You can fight it if you want, but you're going to lose.

Comment: In my case, I need to call a SOAP web service where the endpoint requires the namespace to be declared as an attribute on a element. Their service should probably be redesigned but that is outside of my control and therefore having that flexibility built in the JAXB library would have been nice...