# jaxb namespaces in each element instead of root element during marshalling

Tags: namespaces, jaxb, marshalling, root, jaxb2

By default, jaxb 2 lists all (all possible required) namespaces in root element during marshalling:

> `<rootElement xmlns="default_ns" xmlns:ns1="ns1" xmlns:ns2="ns2">
>        <ns1:element/>
>      </rootElement>`

Is there a way to describe namespace in each element instead of root element ?:

> `<rootElement xmlns="default_ns">
>         <element xmlns="ns1"/>
>      </rootElement>`

It also solves the problem of "unnecessary namespaces", which is also important in my case.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Please don't ask the same thing twice.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385405/jaxb-lists-namespaces-in-root-element-each-element

Comment: excuse me, that post was commited without example

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative, JAXB does not support such low-level customization. Consider using XSLT to post-process the marshalled XML.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I tend to agree wtih @Anton in the response he offered in the other thread.
I really *shouldn't* matter. And if you must force one way or the other, you should always prefer the top-level context, especially if you have potentially repeated elements. Repeating the namespace declaration in sibling elements is a waste of space as well as sub-optimal for the parser at the receiving end.