# Sending only needed namespaces in CXF web services messages

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm using CXF for web services server.
I have a very large number of namespaces on the server.
Each time a request is handled instead of putting only the relevant namespace used in the answer all server's namespaces are dumped into soap answer even if most of them aren't required in the answer's data.
For example:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<ns61:Response 
  xmlns:ns125="http://www.example.com/example125/Example125" 
  xmlns:ns124="http://www.example.com/example124/Example124" 
  xmlns:ns123="http://www.example.com/example123/Example123" 
  xmlns:ns122="http://www.example.com/example122/Example122" 
  xmlns:ns121="http://www.example.com/example121/Example121" 
  ...
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/example1/Example1"
```

Is there a way to force CXF to add only needed namespaces into the soap answer?
Probably related to: [JAXB lists namespaces in root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385405/jaxb-lists-namespaces-in-root-element-each-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CXF is using JAXB for XML serialization and by the information in the above link it seems there isn't an easy way to do such a thing without writing a costly interceptor which will need to read the entire document and remove the redundant namespaces.